# Trapezoidal rule to approximate the integral of x^2

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I've implemented the trapezoidal rule to compute the integral for a function \$x^2\$. I would like to see another style of the same code. It seems Matlab hates for a matrix to be expanded without specifying the size.

```
clear all 
clc
n = 5; % number  subdivisions
a = 1.0; % lower limit
b = 2.0; % upper limit
sum = 0.0;
dx = (b-a)/(n-1); % step size

% Generate samples
for i = 1:n
    x(i) = a + (i-1)*dx; 
end

% Generate function's values
for i = 1:n
    y(i) = x(i).^2;
end

% Compute area using Trapz. method 
for i = 1:n
    if ( i == 1 || i == n) % for the first and last data
        sum = sum + y(i)./2;
    else
        sum = sum + y(i); % for the rest of data
    end
end
area = sum * dx;


area
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to be correct as the integral of \$x^2\$ from 1 to 2 using 5 areas (4 subdivisions) is supposed to be 2.34 exactly, while your code seems to yield the answer for 4 areas (2.3438)

Comment: @mleyfman, don't forget the error. The result `2.3333` not what you said `2.34` is using the analytical form of the function however trapezoidal method is a method to approximate the analytical function. The error here is `0.45 %` which means we have some level of uncertainty in the estimated result.

Comment: I was going by this: http://nastyaccident.com/calculators/calculus/trapezoidalRule. The integral is indeed 2.333 if done analytically. Trapezoidal rule with n=5 should yield 2.34 exactly, whereas n=4 should yield 2.34375

Comment: @mleyfman, according to the link you gave `Answer: 2.34375
` which is same of mine. Even though `n=5` in my code but the loop start from `0` to `4`. Check the implementation of my code.

Comment: Are you sure you ran it with amount=5? Also see this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+using+trapezoidal+rule+with+5+intervals+from+1+to+2

Comment: @mleyfman, I have `y0, y1, y2, y3, y4 = 5` however the subdivided areas is `4` (i.e. `y0-y1, y1-y2,  y2-y3,  y3-y4 = 4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16578/discussion-between-mleyfman-and-croco).

Comment: @mleyfman, you are right. I've changed the comment. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Avoid variable names that collide with built-in functions

`sum` is a built-in function.  Redefining it causes unconventional behavior:

> ```
> >> sum([1 2 3])
>
> ans =
>
>      6
>
> >> sum = 0.0
>
> sum =
>
>      0
>
> >> sum([1 2 3]) 
> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> >> clear all
> >> sum([1 2 3])
>
> ans =
>
>      6
> ```

#### Idiomatic MATLAB

The whole point of using MATLAB, rather than C, is that the language is designed to work on many values at once.  Therefore, you should avoid looping wherever possible, and let MATLAB do its job on vectors.

```
% Givens
n = 5                                  % number of subdivisions
a = 1.0                                % x coordinate left endpoint
b = 2.0                                % x coordinate right endpoint

x = linspace(a, b, n)                  % x coordinates of samples
y = x .^ 2                             % y coordinates of samples
sum_y = sum(y) - (y(1) + y(end)) ./ 2  % sum y coordinates, taking just half of endpoints
dx = (b - a) / (n - 1)                 % width of each trapezoid
area = sum_y * dx
```

#### Reinventing the wheel

For your information, MATLAB has built-in support for numerical integration:

> ```
> >> integral(@(x) x .^ 2, 1, 2)
>
> ans =
>
>     2.3333
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside that I don't know MATLAB, I would like to mention some things

**Naming**

If you need a comment to explain a variable then the variable is poorly named.

> ```
> n = 5; % number subdivided areas
> a = 1.0; % lower limit
> b = 2.0; % upper limit
> dx = (b-a)/(n-1); % step size
> ```

should become

```
subdividedAreaCount = 5;
lowerLimit = 1.0;
upperLimit = 2.0;
stepSize = (upperLimit - lowerLimit) / (subdividedAreaCount -1 );
```

**Refactoring**

Now the loops for generating samples and function values would look like this if we also rename `x` and `y` to `sampleValue` and `functionValue`.

```
% Generate samples
for i = 1:subdividedAreaCount
    sampleValue(i) = lowerLimit + (i-1)*stepSize; 
end

% Generate function values
for i = 1:subdividedAreaCount
    functionValue(i) = sampleValue(i).^2;
end
```

The computing of the area would look like

```
% Compute area using Trapz. method 
for i = 1:subdividedAreaCount
    if ( i == 1 || i == subdividedAreaCount) % for the first and last data
        sum = sum + functionValue(i)./2;
    else
        sum = sum + functionValue(i); % for the rest of data
    end
end
```

but we can refactor this also to exclude the `if` condition like

```
% Compute area using Trapz. method 
for i = 2:subdividedAreaCount-1
    sum = sum + functionValue(i); % for the rest of data
end 
sum = sum + functionValue(2)./2;
sum = sum + functionValue(subdividedAreaCount)./2;
```

Comment: +1 for naming variables. Is there any benefit of refactoring `if` statement? I think mine is more readable than the approach you stated.

Comment: This just depends how big `subdividedAreaCount` can be. If `subdividedAreaCount = 100000` it would be at least faster without using the `if` .